# Maneira correta de fazer relacionamento One To Many usando C# e MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-csharp

Tenho duas entidades, `Sistema` e `Comentario` onde um sistema pode ter vários comentários:

```
   public class Sistema
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("SistemaId")]
        public int SistemaId { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Key")]
        public int Key { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Comentarios")]
        public List<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; }
    }
```

Entidade Comentário:

```
public class Comentario
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

}
```

A ideia é que o resultado final seja parecido com isso:

```
{
       _id: "3213",
       SistemaId: 11701,
       Key: 01
       comentarios: [
                    {
                      _Id: "1",
                      Mensagem: "Comentário 1",
                      DataCriacao: "2016-07-05"
                    },
                    {
                      _Id: "2",
                      Mensagem: "Comentário 2",
                      DataCriacao: "2016-07-06"
                    }
                  ]
     }
```

Essa é a maneira correta de fazer essa relação?

Comment: `Comentario` é sempre subdocumento de `Sistema`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essa é a maneira correta de fazer essa relação?

Sim, considerando que `Comentario` está principalmente relacionado a um `Sistema`. `Comentario` será definido como um subdocumento de `Sistema`.

O que pode ter faltado, caso queira, é uma `DBRef` para o autor do comentário, se for do seu interesse que o autor do comentário seja um usuário do sistema:

```
public class Comentario
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public DBRef Autor { get; set; }
}
```

Uso:

```
var autor = db.FollowReference<Usuario>(comentario.Autor);
```

Comment: Obrigado, não tinha pensando na possibilidade de usar DBRef rs.